# TreeView with buttons

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls, treeviewitem

I have a TreeView where each node has an icon and a descriptive text. But I do not want any node can be selected. Instead, I want that each node act as a button. It run a command when the user press it. But it may not look like a button or hyperlink

This is what I tried so far. The problem is that the text is blue and the text underlined. In addition, sometime the node is selected and therefore blue.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ListGroupViewModel}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontWeight="Bold" ></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ListNodeViewModel}">
        <TextBlock> 
            <Hyperlink TextDecorations="{x:Null}" Command="{Binding ClickCommand, Mode=OneTime}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Margin="0,2,2,0" Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override hyperlink style:

```
        <Style x:Key="HyperlinkStyle" TargetType="Hyperlink">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="TextDecorations"
                    Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ListNodeViewModel}">
            <TextBlock> 
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ClickCommand, Mode=OneTime}"
                           Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkStyle}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Margin="0,2,2,0" Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
```

To hide tree item selection you could override SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, which tree view uses to highlight items:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: Great. Works just fine ... except for one detail. A selected group have normally blue background and white foreground. Now the background will remain white, but the text is changed to white, which means that the text disappears when selected.
Lyssna
Läs fonetiskt
Ordbok - Visa detaljerad ordbokpronomen0.its0.your0.their0.his0.her

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your problem because of   insufficient information. For example, I don't understand why you need to create two data templates, where you set up foregrounds/backgrounds and how you manipulate with tree item on selection. More details, code, images, descriptions will help.

Comment: Nodes containing other nodes have no icons and has a different format than the leaf nodes. So I use HierarchicalDataTemplate to format them. But when I select a node that contains other nodes, the text color are changed automatically to white.

 But I have managed to solve it by using: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />

I have just one question. What should I do to avoid hard-coding "Black". Can I use any "{x:Static SystemColors"?

Comment: I solved it. I changed it to: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />